# How can I share data between functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why can't I call variables (a and b) from function3? I have them defined in my other functions, but when I try to use function3, Python tells me
`NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

```
def function1():
    a = 10

def function2():
    b = 10

def function3(a, b):
    print(a + b)

print(function3(a, b))
```

Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: This looks like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You would get right answer (30), if you just leave out def function1(): and function3(a) (and same for function2. I'm not sure why you want to put a and b for separate namespaces?

Comment: @Selcuk I wanted to send a data from Function1, Function2 altogether to Function 3 and get the result.

Comment: That's not what you are trying to accomplish, that's _how you plan to accomplish it_.

Comment: Were you meant to use the `data` parameter of function3 _in_ function3? The way you're doing it, it seems more like you want to set two global variables a & b and then want function3 to provide a result using them. Depending on global variables with changing values for state before/after calling functions is **not** recommended and will lead to hard to read & debug code. If you really must, then create an object (class) with fields a & b and pass that into func3. Or a class initialised with a & b and has a method func3. Cleaner and obvious intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want data from other functions, you will need to `return` their value(s).

```
def function1():
    return 10

def function2():
    return 10

def function3():
    local_a = function1()
    local_b = function2()
    
    return local_a + local_b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(function3())
```

```
def function1(your_input:int = None):
    """your_input is only local to
       this function unless it's yielded or returned"""

    your_input = your_input if isinstance(your_input, int) else 10

    # The above will check the type of your input.
    # If the type is not an int, it will make your_input equal to 10.

    return your_input

def function2():
    """Since we reconfigured function1, 
        you can now use this function twice instead of duplication.
    """

    local_a = function1()
    local_b = function1()
    # or
    local_c = function1(25)
    local_d = function1(50)

    return local_a + local_b, local_c + local_d

def add_two(num1:int = None, num2:int = None):
    num1 = num1 if isinstance(num1, int) else 0
    num2 = num2 if isinstance(num2, int) else 0
    return num1 + num2
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(function2())
    print(add_two(25,75))
```